# Is there a way to remove urls in decompiled apk file?

Tags: android

Is there a way to remove urls in decompiled apk file?
I know we can remove logs through progaurd like this

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** w(...);
}
```

I have an application on decompiled i can still see the url .Is it possible to encrypt that so that its not visible to everyone?

Comment: The best you can do is to obfuscate them a bit so that they are not immediately visible. But don't get a false feeling of security: an attacker with enough energy will always be able to retrieve them. (I assume they cannot be completely removed because they are needed at runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a customer Log Manager,and control the log print.
when you release your apk，you close it .